# How to write an action class for an MVC web application in JSP?

Tags: model-view-controller, jsp, jakarta-ee

I have followed this tutorial for developing a Java EE application in MVC pattern. But I was asked to write an action classes for complete MVC. The tutorial does not contain an action class.

What is the use of an action class and how to create one?

Comment: Can you post the link followed for the tutorial ?

Comment: http://www.datadisk.co.uk/html_docs/jsp/jsp_mvc_tutorial.htm. I followed this

Comment: Action class is probably a servlet .To control the flow and navigation of jsp pages servlets can be used.

Comment: Can you give a template of it?How to do for a user login operation?

Comment: login using jsp http://www.codemiles.com/jsp-examples/login-using-jsp-t3417.html

Answer (score 1):

action class is basically your controller which processes the request made by client to server ..

login usinh jsp ..(if ur using lookupdispatch action)

```
package com.pra.loginmodel;

public class LoginAction extends LookupDispatchAction {

    /*
     * forward name="success" path=""
     */
    private static final String SUCCESS = "success";

    @Override
    protected Map getKeyMethodMap() {
        Map map = new HashMap();
        map.put("UserForm.login", "login");
        return map;
    }

    public ActionForward login(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,
            HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws Exception {

        LoginActionFormBean lafb = (LoginActionFormBean) form;
        String userid = lafb.getUserid();
        if (!"false".equals(lafb.loginvalidate())) {
            HttpSession session = request.getSession();
            session.setAttribute("user", userid);
            FormBean fb = new FormBean();
            r.setUserid(userid);
            r.show();
            return mapping.findForward(LOGGER);
        } else {
            return mapping.findForward(LOGGER);
        }
    }
}
```

here logincvalidate is function where u match userid and password with ur database ... 
this is simple action class u can use for login jsp